# Returning errors back from ajax to trigger laravel flash messages

Tags: ajax, session, laravel-5

Is it possible to trigger a flash message from an ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/product/destroy/',
    type: 'post',
    data: {id:id, _method: 'delete', _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}' },
     success:function(data) {
       //trigger the flash message here
    } 
  });
```

I suppose you need access to the session in laravel?

Comment: Is it not ok to append some specified error div after ajax return flash message !!

Comment: yes, but it would be nice to tap into the Laravel system thought here may be some sort of ajax 'bridge'. I suppose using ES6 template syntax makes it a bit easier.